# Need to create a function with argument in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0, exslt

Need small help in creating a function with parameter and that can be used in my template. Tried many things but nothing worked out. Below is my sample code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:my="http://exslt.org/my"
    exclude-result-prefixes="my"
    extension-element-prefixes="my math func">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    
    <xsl:variable name="functionTest11"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="my:calXY('aa')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <xsl:variable name="functionTest22"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="my:calXY" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:comment>functionTest <xsl:copy-of
              select="$functionTest22" /></xsl:comment>
        </svg>

    </xsl:template>
    
    <func:function name="my:calXY">
        <xsl:comment>functionHello </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:param name="string1" select="''"/>
        <func:result>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(10,'|',10)" />
        </func:result>
    </func:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  Do you have reason to believe that it supports EXSLT-style user-defined functions?  What error is your processor raising, or what results is it returning?

Comment: Hi @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Below is the error i get :ERROR:  'Cannot find class 'my'.'

FATAL ERROR:  'Cannot find external method 'my.calXY' (must be public).'
** Transformer Factory error
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot find external method 'my.calXY' (must be public).

Comment: If you add that error code (and the answers to the other questions I mentioned) to your question, the question will have a better chance of finding an answer.

Comment: I am new to XSLT. I am using this with Java 1.7 for compiling. Version of XSLT is 1.0.          Yes it is supporting EXSLT as i am using xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" in my XSLT. Let me know if you need any more info.@C.M.Sperberg-McQueen

Answer (score 5):

I don't have convenient access (that I know of) to Xalan, which appears to be the XSLT processor you are using.  So I cannot test any conjectures about the origin of your problem.

But it would surprise me a great deal if putting an output instruction like `xsl:comment` before the first (and only) `xsl:param` were correct. (It surprises me that you don't report any error messages from the stylesheet compiler.  But it's clear from the error message you quote that Xalan has not successfully compiled the function.) It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish by having your function return both a comment node and the string value '10|10', but this is probably not the way to accomplish it.

On the assumption that the `xsl:comment` instruction is an attempt to verify that the function has in fact been evaluated, I'd try something like

```
<func:function name="my:calXY">
    <xsl:param name="string1" select="''"/>
    <func:result select="concat(10,'|',10)" />
</
```

[In an earlier version of this answer, I speculated that `func:result` is not needed here; my error.  It does appear to be needed.]

---

You ask for a complete stylesheet.  The following stylesheet functions as expected when run with xsltproc.  (As I noted above, I don't have a convenient way to run Xalan.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:my="http://example.org/my"
    exclude-result-prefixes="my"
    extension-element-prefixes="func">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message>Result is <xsl:value-of select="my:dummy('foo')"/></xsl:message>
    <output>
      <test><xsl:value-of select="my:dummy('bar')"/></test>
      <test><xsl:value-of select="my:dummy('baz')"/></test>
    </output>    
  </xsl:template>

  <func:function name="my:dummy">
    <xsl:param name="s" select="'foo'"/>
    <func:result select="concat($s,'|',$s)" />
  </func:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen  xsl:comment was used for only verifying if method is been called. func:result is been used to returning the value from where is been called. I have already tried the sample function which you have shared but i get the same error which i have mentioned in my comment. If possible can you plz share any XSLT 1.0 file which have function in it and been called from <template>. Thanks in advance